# Is it a good idea to include price in an ad?

Tags: marketing, pricing

Disclaimer: I have no idea where to ask this question. https://ux.stackexchange.com/ seems to be the best fit.

Imagine we have an ad running on Facebook. Is it a good idea to include the price for the product the ad is marketing in the ad (e.g. get this for $300) or is the idea to just lure them with the ad and get them to click through to the site (where the price will then be stated)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, why not? If the price is one of the main decisive factors, I cannot see anything against it. You should just make sure that the price user will see after clicking the ad is the same (which is most difficult when speaking abou distribution through many indeoendent channels, out of which each can set price which is different from the suggested one).

By the way, this question does touch the topic of User Experience, but it does not address it directly - I think this is more about marketing techniques.

Comment: personally, I would be happy to see more marketing people trying to make their ads a product which offers the viewer a good viewing experience, as opposed to ones which try to annoy or distract her enough to get her to look at them, ones which maskerade as non-promotional content to trap them into clicking, or ones which instill neuroses by suggesting that you are not a happy, fulfilled human being if you don't eat the same yogurt as your neighbour.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most annoying things about buying is finding the price. Either on a normal store or in a website.

If the price is not clearly visible, you give the idea of hidden costs and unfriendliness towards your clients; if you show them you are open and will avoid false hopes, all your visitor will be there because they want to know more about the product or buy it.

About if it belongs here, certainly belongs to other areas, but it also belongs here, in my opinion. It belongs because is part of the experience you provide to the user, not only because it's the cost of something, but because it's information you provide, plus it should reflect the general attitude of your site/store and how you are going to interact with the user.